# Accessing factors in column C of matrix M1 that appear in column C' of matrix M2 - in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a 73335x2882 data frame df and I would like to extract particular rows based on the factors of column df$rs. In order to make my problem understandable, I have created a mini data frame u.

```
> rs = c("rs1","rs2","rs3","rs4","rs5")
> m = matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15),nrow=5)
> u=data.frame(rs,m)
> u
 rs X1 X2 X3
 1 rs1  1  6 11
 2 rs2  2  7 12
 3 rs3  3  8 13
 4 rs4  4  9 14
 5 rs5  5 10 15
```

Now, I create another data frame w.

```
> mat = matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6),nrow=2)
> rs = c("rs3","rs5")
> w = data.frame(rs, mat)
> w
  rs X1 X2 X3
1 rs3  1  3  5
2 rs5  2  4  6
```

What I would like to do is now extract all rows from u for which u$rs is contained in w$rs. Hence, I would like to obtain as a final answer:

```
   rs X1 X2 X3
3 rs3  3  8 13
5 rs5  5 10 15
```

I have tried the following with no success:

```
> u[w$rs,]
   rs X1 X2 X3
1 rs1  1  6 11
2 rs2  2  7 12
```

I also tried

```
> subset(u, rs == w$rs)
Error in Ops.factor(rs, w$rs) : level sets of factors are different
In addition: Warning message:
In is.na(e1) | is.na(e2) :
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

I understand that I could use apply (or a loop) and verify if each factor of u$rs is an element of w$rs. But I am not satisfied with that because it will be extremely slow.

Does anyone have an idea on how to implement this efficiently?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You can try,

```
u[u$rs %in% w$rs, ]
#    rs X1 X2 X3
# 3 rs3  3  8 13
# 5 rs5  5 10 15
```

Answer (score 1):

Or using `data.table`, we convert the 'u' to 'data.table' and join with the 'rs' column of 'w' `on` 'rs'.

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.6+
setDT(u)[w['rs'], on='rs']
#    rs X1 X2 X3
#1: rs3  3  8 13
#2: rs5  5 10 15
```